# looping through one-line csv and inserting values into variables in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have csv with one line in it:

```
4568; John; Doe; email@email.com
```

What I need to do in PowerShell is to loop through this line and save the values into separate variables.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Take a look at `Import-Csv`, this should cover everything you need. And please try to come up with an solution yourself before asking ;) Also take a look at [ask] and try to offer an[mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way.

```
$id,$fname,$lname,$email = (Get-Content -Path '.\thefile.csv') -split '; '
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
$csv = "4568; John; Doe; email@email.com" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header ID,Givenname,Name,Email -Delimiter ";"

$csv.Id
$csv.Givenname
$csv.Name
$csv.Email
```